# Is my formData to big to be sent through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, object

I collect data into a JS object:

```
var elements = {};
    
$(checked).each(function(i){
        
    elements[i] = {};
    elements[i].obj = obj;
    elements[i].el = $(this).data('el');
    elements[i].height = $(this).data('height');
    elements[i].type = $(this).data('type');
    elements[i].length = $(this).data('length');
    elements[i].width = $(this).data('width');
    elements[i].weight = $(this).data('weight');
    elements[i].created_by = $(this).data('created_by');
        
});
```

Then I'm sending it via an Ajax request:

```
//SEND TO PHP
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "php/i.php",
    data: {elements: elements, obj: obj},
    success: function(result){
       
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

This works if the elements obj isn't too big. (I guess).

Is there a limit of size i need to change somewhere?
I have no problem uploading big files like photos etc.

This two dumps represent one Ajax call that works and have data in PHP $_POST,
and one where $_POST returns empty.. i guess it's the size that that makes the difference?!

[image: 2]

[image: 1]

Comment: Check what `max_input_vars` is set to in your php.ini. That setting limits the amount of input fields that PHP can receive per request. In most PHP installations I've seen, it's set to 1000 as default, while it looks like you're sending 1321.

Comment: `max_input_vars` is 1000 by default (as Magnus pointed out). There is more information on how to update it on the PHP manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).

Comment: You're right it is set to 1000. But it is disabled by a ; I will change it and let you know :)

Comment: Fantastic! It worked! Thank you guys!